# Происхождение слова "огурец"

Tags: этимология

Давно интересно, а от какого слова произошло слово "огурец"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Огурец. Происходит от ср.-греч. ἄγουρος «огурец», нов.-греч. ἄγουρος (наряду с более распространенным ἀγγούρι — то же). Русск. огурец — из др.-русск. огурець (Домостр. К. 4). *Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера.*